# Find out which shell PHP is using

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, php

I'm trying to execute a piped shell commands like this

> set -o pipefail && command1 | command2 | command3

from a PHP script. The `set -o pipefail` part is to make the pipe break as soon as any of the commands fails. But the commands results in this:

> sh: 1: set: Illegal option -o pipefail

whereas it runs fine from the terminal. Maybe explicitly specifying which shell PHP CLI should use (i.e. `bin/bash`) when executing shell commands could solve the problem or is there better way out?

Comment: @RPM Aww, it doesn't. But thing like `var_dump($_SERVER);` does..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always run `bash -c 'set -o pipefail && command1 | command2 | command3'` instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can find it out by doing

```
echo `echo $SHELL`;
```

Comment: Maybe running `echo $_SERVER["SHELL"]` from PHP would be more straightforward.